# The Flutter rate_my_app package does not work in testflight, but it does on the simulator and on iPhone/iPad devices

Tags: xcode, flutter

I have am using the flutter package **rate_my_app** and it works on my iPhone/iPad and the simulator, but does not work in test flight. I tried building it in release mode and I get an error.

```
Try launching Xcode and selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
```

I go to Xcode and it install on my iPhone, and the module work great. I am not sure what I am missing.